How to config parameter "LOAD_KEXEC" for Ubuntu24.04?
I want to trigger a crash on Ubuntu 24.04 but I noticed the document(https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/kernel-crash-dump) for Ubuntu did not match the current configuration. The "LOAD_KEXEC" parameter in the file "/etc/default/kexec" seems to have been removed On Ubuntu24.04. Do I need to add "LOAD_KEXEC=true" manually?
